# get coordinates of wikimapia class instances without API

Tags: parsing, wikimapia

It seems that the wikimapia API isn't working at the moment.

I'm wondering whether there's a way to obtain location data from wikimapia without using the API, e.g. by parsing the webpage source code.

For example, let's say I want to obtain the locations of the train stations in the northwest of Italy.

These [can easily be displayed on wikimapia](http://wikimapia.org/#lang=en&lat=45.897655&lon=13.081970&z=9&m=b&tag=44751) (by showing category "train station", category (tag) id 44751).

Can this information be extracted from the page linked to above without recourse to the API?

Comment: Yes. You can download the page and parse its content. You could also ask the people operating the website for a copy of their data store or access to it (you could then offer them help fixing the API as well).

Comment: I'll clarify my question: I tried looking where in the page source the relevant information is, by e.g. looking for the category tag (44751 in this case) or lists of latitude and longitude, or station names, but the structure of the files is still pretty obscure to me, so I can't find my way around yet.